# PHP variable being reset when run from command line

Tags: php, arrays, reset

In file config.php

```
$_CONFIG = array();
require_once("config.inc.php");
var_dump($_CONFIG);
```

In file config.inc.php

```
$_CONFIG = array('x' => 'y', ...);
var_dump($_CONFIG);
```

The output of this code, when run from the command line is:

```
array(15) {
  ["x"]=>
  string(1) "y"
  ...
}
array(0) {
}
```

If I remove the first line of config.php which initializes the empty $_CONFIG array, the script works, and the var_dumps are identical.

Note that this is a script run from a command line. Any idea why this is happening? I've tried this on two separate machines, one with PHP 5.3.3 and the other with PHP 5.3.5.

**Update** - This only seems to be an issue with the command line. When run from a browser, it seems fine. Also, there is a third file I forgot to mention, which is including config.php

test.php

```
require_once("/path/to/config.php");
```

When running **test.php**, not config.php from the command line, I get the output above.

Comment: I created the same files and see expected result - the same array twice. Could you reproduce it with 2 small files?

Comment: Works exactly as expected for me.. PHP 5.3.10.

Comment: are you sure you told us everything what's in those files? `php --version` ?

Comment: When you define $_CONFIG inside config.inc.php, do you do it inside a function? The problem can to be related to global variables not being accessible, so, the "redefinition" is taken as a different local variable (i.e. a problem with the scope of the variables).

Comment: @yi_H PHP version 5.3.3. `config.inc.php` only populates the $_CONFIG array, though I've truncated it. `config.php` contains more code following the `var_dump` but nothing before it except comments, and nothing in between those 3 lines.

Comment: @jap1968 No, it is not defined within a function.

Comment: @andrewtweber: could you create 2 small files and share the archive with them?

Comment: is the file really included? is the path correct?

Comment: @markus-tharkun yes, otherwise the first var_dump would not output anything.

Comment: Try to ``return`` the config array instead of using $_CONFIG directly in the included file and assign it to ``$_CONFIG``: ``$_CONFIG = require_once('file.php')``. This does not explain the problem, but it is a better programming style :-)

Answer (score 2):

The situation you describe does not produce the output you describe. There is something else going on in; there is additional code not placed in the question.

From a very simple test:

```
$ ls -la
-rw-rw-r--   1 jon jon    59 2012-02-28 20:37 config.inc.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 jon jon    83 2012-02-28 20:37 config.php

$ cat config.*
<?php
$_CONFIG = array('x' => 'y');
var_dump($_CONFIG);
?>
<?php

$_CONFIG = array();
require_once('config.inc.php');
var_dump($_CONFIG);

?>
$ php config.php
array(1) {
  ["x"]=>
  string(1) "y"
}
array(1) {
  ["x"]=>
  string(1) "y"
}
```

Possible causes of the output you see:

- config.inc.php uses a namespace, defining a new copy of $_CONFIG not in the global namespace
- `require_once('config.inc.php');` is checking your include path first and is including a different config.inc.php to the one you are expecting

Comment: It is not including a different config.inc.php file, because otherwise there would be no var_dump (i.e. any edits I made to that file were immediately evident in the output). I forgot to mention though that there is a third file including config.php. So I would run that 3rd file from the command line, not config.php itself.